# how to stop socket with linux command?

Tags: sockets

how to stop socket in linux :

socket ==>

```
root@root:/home/aa/test# netstat | grep 3966      
tcp        0      0 server:3966       server:57004       TIME_WAIT
```

thank

Answer (score 7):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo netstat -ap | grep :<port_number>
```

Also you can try this to close the socket connection

```
tcpkill -i eth0 host xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and port yyyy
```

Replace X with the IP address, and Y with the port number.

also take a look at [tcpkill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcpkill) and [cutter command](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/cutting-the-tcpip-network-connection-with-cutter.html)

---

Comment: this command don't close socket !!!!

Comment: When I try to run the command  I got this error :

pcap_compile: syntax error
tcpkill: couldn't initialize sniffing

Comment: A `sudo` before tcpkill might help

Comment: Does not work... `sudo: tcpkill: command not found`

Comment: @kwoxer use this command to install `tcpkill`. `sudo apt-get install dsniff`

Comment: Well I solved it with `kill -9 ...`. No use of an extra tool. Worked well with kill.